# git: cannot merge with upstream

Tags: git, github

I have made some changes on my forked repository, and I wish to overwrite a single file from upstream. The upstream repository is added as a remote. When I perform a merge, git tells me I am up to date:

```
$ git merge upstream/master master
Already up-to-date.
```

But when I run diff, git shows the missing file for my forked repository

```
$ git diff upstream/master origin
diff --git a/Library/Formula/exim.rb b/Library/Formula/exim.rb
deleted file mode 100644
index 48d52cf..0000000
--- a/Library/Formula/exim.rb
```

Is there anyway to get git to add in the missing file to my forked repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upstream has the file. You had it from upstream and deleted it. 3-way merge of no change versus delete is delete, therefore the file is still not there after the merge. Once `upstream/master` is fully merged (which is the case given your first listed output), merging again is a no operation, because merge only considers changes since the branches were last merged and there are none on the other side.

You want to either:

- revert the change in which you deleted the file:

  ```
  git log -- Library/Formula/exim.rb
  ```

  will tell you the revision where you removed the file and than

  ```
  git revert <revision-id>
  ```

  to revert it.
- get the file's content from upstream and add it again:

  ```
  git cat-file blob upstream/master:Library/Formula/exim.rb > Library/Formula/exim.rb
  git add Library/Formula/exim.rb
  git commit
  ```

Comment: `git reset --hard upstream/master` followed by `git push -f origin master` solved the problem.

Comment: ... so you just discarded all your experiments done so far; but fine (and you still have them in the reflog).

Comment: Yes, because the upstream author has merged in the change anyway. I have to say `git log -- <filename>` was illuminating to me. I did use `git revert`. Since I don't care for any of my changes, I just reset to the upstream master. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do the merge to your local master like so :

```
git checkout master
git pull origin/master  # in case there are changes posted remotely
git pull upstream/master
```

After that you can push your local master to the remote `origin` with :

```
git push origin master
```

At this point `upstream/master` should be merged into `master`, which should equal `origin/master`.

---

Also your diff command doesn't make much sense, if you expect them to be equal :

```
git diff upstream/master origin
```

This compares `origin/master` to `upstream/master` but if you made changes on your `master` after you forked and you don't control `upstream` these can't be equal, it seems you expect them to be.

Comment: Yes, I run fetch before attempting to merge.

Comment: Yes, I'm a little confused at what you are trying to do with `origin` in the diff.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing `upstream/master` with `origin/master`, but merging `upstream/master` into `master`. It looks like you're confused between `upstream` repo (the original repo on GitHub) and `origin` (your forked repo on GitHub).

Once you merged changes, they're still local, if you want to make them appear in `origin` you need to push them: `git push origin master`.

Graphically you have this situation at the beginning:

```
A----B 
\    ^master and origin/master
 \---C 
     ^upstream/master
```

After merge:

```
A----B-----------------D
\    ^origin/master   /^master
 \---C---------------/ 
     ^upstream/master
```

And after pushing back to `origin`:

```
A----B-----------------D
\    ^                /^master and origin/master
 \---C---------------/ 
     ^upstream/master
```

Comment: You are right. `$ git merge upstream/master origin/master
Updating 5727297..73e08a6
Fast-forward
 Library/Formula/exim.rb | 84 -------------------------------------------------
 1 file changed, 84 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 Library/Formula/exim.rb`

I still cannot merge my local repo with the changes from upstream though.

Comment: @hanxue: Your local repo is already merged with upstream. Merging again simply has no effect, because there are no new changes to merge.

Comment: as @schleis says, your changes are still local, if you want to make them appear in `origin` you need to push them: `git push origin master`

Comment: Thank you very much @schleis , @CharlesB & @jan-hudec . Turned out I got confused by the upstream file. `git reset --hard upstream/master` followed by `git push -f origin master` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `git merge` command is not updating the upstream repo.  You telling git to combine the changes from the upstream into your local and because you already have all the commits from the upstream in your local there is nothing to commit.

You want to "push" your changes.  Run `git push upstream master`

http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2012/pushing-to-different-git-remotes

For your forked repo, you only need to do a `git push origin master` to push the master branch or just a simple `git push`

Comment: @CharlesB the upstream repo is a remote repo.  The OP is running the incorrect command to update the upstream.

Comment: Does `git push upstream master` mean pushing changes from my repository into the upstream repository?

Comment: `git push upstream master` will attempt to push the changes to the upstream repository (assuming that you have permissions to do so)

Comment: @Schleis: he doesn't want to update remotely the upstream, but to merge local changes with remote. Also there's little chance that he has writing permissions on the upstream repo.

Comment: My reading is that they want to update some remote repo (I may have originally misunderstood which one).  Either way `merge` is not the correct command.  They are looking for `git push`